# golang didn't free variable after end of the function

Tags: go

I wrote a simple program by golang as below and it did occupy 4GB of memory space and didn't free it after end of the function. How can I free the occupied memory?

```
func main() {
    wait := make(chan bool, 1)
    go func() {
        slice := make([]int64, 0)
        for i := 0; i < 1000 * 1000 * 100; i++ {
            slice = append(slice, 1)
        }
    }()

    <- wait
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the space was not made available for future allocations?

Comment: I thought that after the `go func(){}` end the memory must be returned to the value before running this function

Comment: when running this program, my computer is so slow

Answer (score -1):

GC just mark this memory to useful instead of free it immediately，they will free the unused memory periodically, so it will take some time for memory to be really free.

Comment: when client sends me a http request, I create a large slice and save it to an excel file, I run it in a goroutine, but when the function end, the memory space occupied  is still not be free.

Comment: It will be free, just takes a while about 5min.

Comment: but why is it so slow

Comment: Just trust the GC of Go, don't worry about the memory managment.

Comment: GC just mark this memory to useful instead of free it immediately，they will free the unused memory periodically.